# firstboot starts Xorg with wrong command line

Tags: linux, rhel, xorg, nx

After installinx `nx server`, `gnome` and setting run level 5 in inittab, nx can't connect to X server, but after killing `Xorg` it can.

Looks like I have to accept the license to get rid of `firstboot`, but I only have ssh access.

Initially:

```
# init 3
# init 5

root      7642  7638  2 15:44 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/sbin/firstboot
root      7644  7642  1 15:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xorg :9 -ac -nolisten tcp vt6 -br

# kill 7644

root      7784  7759  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Display1
root      7787  7784  4 15:47 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -audit 4 -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-r4nB6i/database vt1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the "firstboot" service?  `chkconfig firstboot off` (assuming RHEL6) should disable it.  You can also add `firstboot --disable` to your kickstart to disable it during kickstart.